# What is the importance that an assumption needs to state whether a space is Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, self-learning

I am self studying functional analysis and I don't not see the utility of authors trying make it clear that a space $X$ is a Banach space before proceeding with a definition.

For example, going through calculus, I don't recall in our Fourier transform lesson that the professor had to make sure that $X, Y$ were "X" spaces before proceeding with the definition of Fourier transform.

Now I am hesitant to even integrate trivial functions such as $f(x) = x$ because I don't know if integration works on the space that contains $x$.

For example,

> Let $X$, $Y$ be Banach spaces, the directional derivative of $f : X →
> Y$ at $x ∈ U ⊆ X$ in the direction $h ∈ X$, denoted by the symbol
>   $f(x; h)$, is defined by the equation
>
> $$f(x; h) = \lim_{t→0} \frac{f(x + th) − f(x)}{t}$$ whenever the limit
>   on the right exists.

Does it imply that the formula only works between Banach spaces and cannot work on any other space? What if I replaced Banach space in the definition with function space, Hilbert space or simply sets? If so, does that mean I should painstakingly prove that a function is an element of an appropriate functional space before doing even the simplest of calculations?

Why do authors insist on making clear that a space is a Banach space before proceeding with a definition? How would the definition fail if $X, Y$ were not Banach space?

Comment: Directional derivative does make in weaker spaces. However, if you want to define (higher order) differential with the usual calculus rules, then Banach spaces are the natural setting. Also very useful, you can define integral for functions into Banach spaces in a natural way.

Answer (score 1):

A Banach space is a complete normed space. If it is not complete, you loose a lot of things. Just like you loose things if you don't work with $\mathbb{R}$, and work only with $\mathbb{Q}$ (since not every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ converge to a point in $\mathbb{Q}$...but every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ converge to a point in $\mathbb{R}$; that's why $\mathbb{R}$ is called a complete metric space).